# Recommendations: asynchronous, portable file io in c++

Tags: c++, asynchronous, io, portability

I'm looking for a C++, async io library that should be compatible with both unix and windows systems.

What are some good libraries? Is this asking too much for a library that does both systems? What are peoples' experiences with this matter?

Answer (score 4):

Use [boost::asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) with [boost::iostreams](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html) instead of asio streams. ASIO provides asynchronousness, while IOStreams provide powerful portable IO options.

Answer (score 3):

Try to take a look at [boost::asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html). I've never personally used it but I heard good things about it.

Comment: The OP is looking for *file* I/O, whereas Boost.Asio is primarily network oriented.

Comment: It's possible to attach normal files to these.  But I'm not sure it's very portable once you get into that and he is wanting portability

Comment: It also has file support. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/378515/whats-the-deal-with-boost-asio-and-file-i-o . It however appears that it's windows-only, I didn't know that (boost usually is very portable)

Comment: yes, i've looked at boost, it seems to separate the unix and windows code...so it *seems* like I shouldn't use boost.