# QDir hangs on accessing CIFS remote folder when disconnected

Tags: qt, timeout, share, mount, cifs

I'm using Qt 4.7 on CentOS 6.0.
I have a remote share folder mounted with CIFS:

```
mount -t cifs //PC128/mnt /media/net -o username=user,password=pwd,rw,noexec,soft,uid=user,gid=user
```

When remote folder is somehow incorrectly disconnected (e.g. the network cable is pulled out) my application hangs because of QDir locks on attempt to touch the folder (e.g. QDir::exists call). After ~90 seconds it unlocks and returns false.

It looks right - the timeout to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QDir` uses synchronous file API. When underlying file system freezes, it freezes too. There are 2 options to avoid GUI freeze:

`1.` Move file operations to a separate thread. Use signal/slot connection to request the thread to perform `QDir::exists` call and to pass the result back into the GUI thread. If the filesystem freezes, only the background thread will be frozen. GUI will still operate.

`2.` Use a library that uses asynchronous file API. Any request made by this library will return control flow to your app immediately. The result will be passed to the callback function. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417583/how-to-perfrom-cross-platform-asynchronous-file-i-o-in-c) for available options.

Comment: I tried to research further about CIFS timeouts, but it seams that there is no way to change them. So yeah, I'm going to implement solution 1 + manual timeouts.