Efficient approach to read from a file and dump its data to other files in C++
I have a requirement that I need to split a file into multiple smaller files and I am trying to figure out what is the most efficient way to read and write to a file in C++. I tried two approaches:

Using ifstream and ofstream directly to read and write a file line by line.
Using a ostringstream buffer to get all the data from the input file in a buffer and then writing it the output file.

On benchmarking, I found that the 2nd approach is way more better than the 1st.
Is there anything which I am missing, which can affect the performance of the code?
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>
const int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;

class FileWriter {
    private:
        std::ofstream m_OutFile;
        char m_CharBuffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

    public:
        FileWriter(const std::string& filename) {
            m_OutFile.open(filename.c_str(), std::ios::out);
            m_OutFile.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(m_CharBuffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
        }

        ~FileWriter() {
            m_OutFile.close();
        }

        void WriteToFile(std::ostringstream& oStr) {
            oStr << std::ends;
            m_OutFile << oStr.str() << std::endl;
            oStr.str("");
        }
};

void fileWriterV2 (std::string inp, std::string out) {
    FileWriter writer(out);
    std::ostringstream oStr;
    std::ifstream inputFile(inp);
    oStr << inputFile.rdbuf();
    writer.WriteToFile(oStr);
}
void fileWriterV1 (std::string inputFilename, std::string outputFilename){
std::ifstream inputFile(inputFilename);
    std::ofstream outputFile(outputFilename);

    if (!inputFile.is_open()) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to open input file: " << inputFilename << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    if (!outputFile.is_open()) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to open output file: " << outputFilename << std::endl;
        inputFile.close();
        return;
    }

    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(inputFile, line)) {
        outputFile << line << std::endl;
    }
    inputFile.close();
    outputFile.close();
}
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    std::string inputFilename = argv[1];
    std::string outputFilename = argv[2];
    // fileWriterV1(inputFilename, outputFilename);
    fileWriterV2(inputFilename, outputFilename)
    auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now(); 
    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - start).count();
    std::cout << "File writing complete in "<< duration << " ms" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}



std::endl inserts a newline character and flushes the stream. You don't need to flush every time. Just use outputFile << line << '\n';. You will see some improvement for 1st option.

outfile << infile.rdbuf();? No need to go through a string stream. Or use a special class for writing to the file.

Obligatory: Are you compiling with optimizations on? Can you provide some results? If you have tested with multiple sizes that would be a bonus.

@RetiredNinja, for a file of size 2.2 GB, the 1st approach is taking roughly 105.14 secs and 2nd approach is taking 10.67 secs.

Depends on the OS. On Linux, your best best is probably to use mmap to memory map the input file (and possibly the output files). On Windows, for a big copy operation like this, you really want to use CreateFile directly, so you can specify FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING. Here's a bit of demo code of the latter: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20393038/179910
