# High performance packet handling in Linux

Tags: linux, performance, linux-kernel, network-programming, arm

I’m working on a packet reshaping project in Linux using the BeagleBone Black. Basically, packets are received on one VLAN, modified, and then are sent out on a different VLAN. This process is bidirectional - the VLANs are not designated as being input-only or output-only. It’s similar to a network bridge, but packets are altered (sometimes fairly significantly) in-transit.

I’ve tried two different methods for accomplishing this:

1. Creating a user space application that opens raw sockets on both
   interfaces. All packet processing (including bridging) is handled in
   the application.
2. Setting up a software bridge (using the kernel
   bridge module) and adding a kernel module that installs a netfilter
   hook in post routing (NF_BR_POST_ROUTING). All packet processing is
   handled in the kernel.

The second option appears to be around 4 times faster than the first option. I’d like to understand more about why this is. I’ve tried brainstorming a bit and wondered if there is a substantial performance hit in rapidly switching between kernel and user space, or maybe something about the socket interface is inherently slow?

I think the user application is fairly optimized (for example, I’m using PACKET_MMAP), but it’s possible that it could be optimized further. I ran perf on the application and noticed that it was spending a good deal of time (35%) in v7_flush_kern_dcache_area, so perhaps this is a likely candidate. If there are any other suggestions on common ways to optimize packet processing I can give them a try.

Comment: Context switches such as user mode/kernel mode/user mode are very quick in all versions of Linux.  The code is found in [entry-common.S swi handler](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/kernel/entry-common.S#n112) and [entry-common.S ret_syscall](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/kernel/entry-common.S#n28). The more likely culprit is buffer copying.  See: [Zero copy vs kernel bypass](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18343365/zero-copy-networking-vs-kernel-bypass).

Comment: That is a context switch from a user app to the kernel and back to the **SAME** user app; there is no MM (memory management) switch.  The scheduler may try to run something else, so you could benefit from an RT priority.  See the 'WORK_FLAG' in ret_syscall, where the re-schedule could happen.

Answer (score 1):

Context switches are expensive and kernel to user space switches imply a context switch. You can see [this article](http://blog.tsunanet.net/2010/11/how-long-does-it-take-to-make-context.html) for exact numbers, but the stated durations are all in the order of microseconds.

You can also use lmbench to benchmark the real [cost of context switches](http://www.bitmover.com/lmbench/lat_ctx.8.html) on your particular cpu.

Answer (score 0):

The performance of the user space application depends on the used syscall to monitor the sockets too. The fastest syscall is epoll() when you need to handle a lot of sockets. select() will perform very poor, if you handle a lot of sockets.

See this post explaining it:
[Why is epoll faster than select?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17355593/why-is-epoll-faster-than-select)

Comment: Thanks for submitting an answer. My application has a single socket and uses poll() to check the socket.