# Strange exception throw - assign: Operation not permitted

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I want to do asynchronous read from cin therefore I have a piece of code

client.h

```
...
boost::asio::posix::stream_descriptor input;
boost::asio::streambuf input_buffer
```

client.cpp

```
Client::Client(int argc, char **argv, boost::asio::io_service &io_service)
    : tcp_socket(io_service)
    , udp_socket(io_service)
    , input(io_service, ::dup(STDIN_FILENO))
{
    ...
    read_std_input();
}

void Client::read_std_input() {
    async_read_until(input, input_buffer, '\n',
                     boost::bind(&Client::handle_std_read, this,
                                 boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                                 boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
}
```

The problem is: when I run my client the normal way [ ./client ] and then input something via command like, it works like charm. 
However, when I run it via [ ./client < test ] it throws :

> terminate called after throwing an instance of
>   'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl
>
> > '   what():  assign: Operation not permitted Aborted

Do you have an idea of what the problem might be?
Thanks!

Comment: You haven't mentioned what platform you are using.   The support for asynchronous file I/O is vastly different on Windows and Linux (and ....)

Comment: im using linux mint 16 64bit

Comment: Have a look with strace to see what syscall might be complaining.

Comment: Can you provide your kernel config? E.g. “Enable AIO support (AIO)” etc. would be interesting

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Boost.Asio's POSIX stream-oriented descriptors explicitly do not support regular files.  Hence, if `test` is a regular file, then `./client < test` will result in [`posix::stream_descriptor::assign()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/posix__basic_stream_descriptor/assign.html) failing when attempting to assign `STDIN_FILENO` to the `stream_descriptor`.  The [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/posix/stream_descriptor.html) states:

> Boost.Asio includes classes added to permit synchronous and asynchronous read and write operations to be performed on POSIX file descriptors, such as pipes, standard input and output, and various devices (but *not* regular files).

Consider passing the contents of the `test` file to `client` through a pipe.

```
$ cat test | ./client
```

---

Here is a complete example program and demonstration:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

void handle_read(
  const boost::system::error_code& error,
  std::size_t bytes_transferred
)
{
  std::cout << "read " << bytes_transferred << " bytes with "
            << error.message() << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  boost::asio::io_service io_service;
  boost::asio::posix::stream_descriptor input(io_service);

  // Assign STDIN_FILENO to the stream_descriptor.  It will support
  // pipes, standard input and output, and various devices, but NOT
  // regular files.
  boost::system::error_code error;
  input.assign(STDIN_FILENO, error);
  if (error)
  {
    std::cerr << error.message() << std::endl;
    return -1;
  }

  boost::asio::streambuf input_buffer;
  async_read_until(input, input_buffer, '\n', &handle_read);
  io_service.run();
}
```

Demonstration

```
$ ./client
testing standard inputenter
read 23 bytes with Success
$ echo "this is a test" > test
$ ./client < test
Operation not permitted
$ cat test | ./client
read 15 bytes with Success
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it explains everything!

Answer (score 2):

Boost asio, on Linux, uses the `epoll` system [by default](https://github.com/chriskohlhoff/asio/blob/master/asio/include/asio/detail/reactor.hpp) which [does not support files](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=15272).

But there's a workaround: if you define `BOOST_ASIO_DISABLE_EPOLL` then asio will revert to the `select` system and files will work.

Answer (score 1):

Asynchronous file I/O on Linux is still rather primitive.  Although the ASIO support for asynchronous file I/O works well in Windows, I haven't had much (...er any) luck using it on Linux.

[This is a previous SO question that provides some background on the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378515/whats-the-deal-with-boost-asio-and-file-i-o).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with this minimal reproducer? It works on my Ubuntu 64-bit box:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/posix/stream_descriptor.hpp>

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using namespace boost::asio;

    io_service io;
    posix::stream_descriptor input(io);

    input.assign(STDIN_FILENO);
    streambuf input_buffer;

    std::function<void()> loop = [&] {
        async_read_until(input, input_buffer, '\n', [&](boost::system::error_code ec, size_t) {
            if (ec) 
                std::cerr << ec.message();
            else {
                std::cout << "LOOP: '" << &input_buffer << "'\n";
                loop();
            }
        });
    };

    loop();
    io.run();
}
```

**Update** I think I can reproduce the problem **[on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3985dd70ff3bec6e)**: can you check the output of `ulimit -a`?

Comment: this code throws as well when passing a file to i/o. here's the output of ulimit -a: http://pastebin.com/WfpNkGjV