# Running boost::asio asynchronous server alongside command loop

Tags: c++, asynchronous, boost, network-programming, boost-asio

I'm trying to create a C++ daemon that is capable of asynchronously sending/receiving requests/responses as packets over the network. It should communicate with clients (outwards-facing message API) and other daemons (inter-server messages)

I'm currently looking at `boost::asio`, specifically http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime6/src.html as a starting point that seems to be running a server capable of handling async. send and receive.

My question is, could this server be run alongside (in the background) a command loop, such as a process responding to user input (e.g. shell)? The daytime server program provided seems to block on the line `io_service.run();`

Would this require a forked or separate threaded server?

Comment: Take a look at [io_service::poll](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/poll/overload1.html) and [poll_one](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/poll_one/overload1.html) member functions - you can interleave these calls with a 3-d party message loop.

Comment: Or just use stream support to read stdin in the first place https://stackoverflow.com/a/23721159/85371

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply create a thread member variable, and let the `io_service` run on the thread. You can process all the process-input in your main-thread, and give your server-class-variable some work to do.

```
std::thread ioThread;
ioThread = std::thread([this]() { io_service.run(); });
```

Do not forget to join the thread later and stop the io_service.

```
io_service.stop();
if (ioThread.joinable())
    ioThread.join();
```