# win7 boost::asio::windows::stream_handle constructor throws error

Tags: windows-7, boost-asio

The following code gets an error when trying to execute the last line

```
 boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::io_service> ioServicePtr(new boost::asio::io_service());
 //setup the terminal with stdin and stdout

 int inFD = ::dup(STDIN_FILENO);

 int outFD = ::dup(STDOUT_FILENO);

 HANDLE osfhandle = (HANDLE)_get_osfhandle(inFD);//osfhandle is valid

 boost::asio::windows::stream_handle inputStream(*ioServicePtr, osfhandle); //error
```

the error is:

```
uncaught exception of type N5boost16exception_detail10clone_implINS0_19error_info_injectorINS_6system12system_errorEEEEE
- assign: The parameter is incorrect
```

Appreciate your input.

@sehe

I tried

```
hstdhandle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
```

and got the same error

So then I tried

```
HANDLE handle= 
CreateFile(
    "CONIN$", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 
    FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, NULL);
boost::asio::windows::stream_handle inputStream(*ioServicePtr, handle);
```

and the error was

```
-assign handle invalid
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might use `GetStdHandle`, so:

```
HANDLE isfhandle = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
```

However, I don't think consoles support asynchronous IO in windows:

- The handle must be to an object that supports overlapped I/O.

  > If a handle is provided, it has to have been opened for overlapped I/O completion. For example, you must
  >   specify the `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` flag when using the CreateFile function to obtain the handle

  But further the docs for CreateFile say that CreateFile ignores file flags when creating a handle to a console buffer.

So, you will need to emulate stdin/stdout async IO.

---

Note that on Linux, asynchronous IO to the standard IO handles is only possible in certain situations anyway - depending on the input/output being redirected: [Strange exception throw - assign: Operation not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23614370/strange-exception-throw-assign-operation-not-permitted)