# Boost asio messes with standard input?

Tags: c++, boost, pipe, boost-asio

This program reads from stdin (via iostream) and writes to stdout (via boost/asio):

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

boost::asio::io_service io_service;
boost::asio::posix::stream_descriptor out(io_service, ::dup(STDOUT_FILENO));
std::string line = "";

static void handler(
    boost::system::error_code const &,
    std::size_t
) {
    assert(std::getline(std::cin, line));
    line += "\n";
    async_write(out, boost::asio::buffer(line), handler);
}

int main()
{
    async_write(out, boost::asio::buffer(line), handler);
    io_service.run();
}
```

build: `g++ -std=gnu++1y -O0 -g3 -o out in.cxx -lboost_system -lboost_thread`

run: `cat | ./out`

output:

```
foo [TERMINAL INPUT]
foo
bar [TERMINAL INPUT]
cat: -: Resource temporarily unavailable
bar
out: in.cxx:14: void handler(const boost::system::error_code&, std::size_t): Assertion `std::getline(std::cin, line)' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

`cat` gets an `EAGAIN` from a `write()` to its standard output, treats it as an error, and closes the pipe. In turn `getline()` fails and the program aborts.

This looks like asio is setting the program's standard input (which is the standard output of `cat`, see [Strange exception throw - assign: Operation not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23614370/strange-exception-throw-assign-operation-not-permitted)) to non-blocking. It has no obvious reason to do this, because it is operating on standard output only, though.

If I get this right, is this a bug in asio? Is there a workaround?

```
libboost1.58-dev/xenial-updates,now 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1 amd64 [installed]
g++/xenial,now 4:5.3.1-1ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
```

Comment: I don't know how you infer that "asio is setting the program's standard input to non-blocking". I don't see that logic. And yes, if you redirect the output of your program to a file then you WILL get `assign: operation not permitted` because async-IO is not supported to files on linux.

Comment: @sehe: `cat` says `-: Resource temporarily unavailable` - so someone must have set the file descriptor to non-blocking. If it was not `cat` or the shell, it must be the program, i.e. asio.

Comment: @sehe: I'm not seeing the `assign: operation not permitted` error here. I only refer to where I learned that both ends of a shell pipe share the same file descriptor.

Comment: Oh. You should have said _that_. Also, I don't see anywhere where that claim is made ("both ends of a shell pipe share the same file descriptor"). More importantly I think it's false and irrelevant. [(fds are local to a process anyways, there is no useful comparison between fds from different processes)](http://lackingrhoticity.blogspot.nl/2015/05/passing-fds-handles-between-processes.html)

Comment: @sehe: Well it is not the same file descriptor, but their file descriptors refer to the same open file. So the flags that one sets (such as `O_NONBLOCK`) will be seen by the other. See my example at http://ideone.com/r4TVZd.

Answer (score 2):

You invoke [Undefined Behaviour](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) here:

```
async_write(out, boost::asio::buffer(string + "\n"), handler);
```

Because the buffer is a local variable it will be destroyed when `handler` exits, before the async write operation may get a chance to run.

**EDIT** Actually, even if the variable wasn't local, the `+ "\n"` makes it a temporary!

Here's a suggested fix for this simple program:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/39f043b32ab1becd)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

boost::asio::io_service io_service;
boost::asio::posix::stream_descriptor out(io_service, ::dup(STDOUT_FILENO));
std::string input_buffer;

static void handler(boost::system::error_code /*error*/, std::size_t /*bytes_transferred*/) {
    if (std::getline(std::cin, input_buffer)) {
        input_buffer += "\n";
        async_write(out, boost::asio::buffer(input_buffer), handler);
    }
}

int main() {
    async_write(out, boost::asio::buffer(""), handler);
    io_service.run();
}
```

I'm not sure this solves all your problems, but at the very least you need to fix it in order to be able to reason about your program *at all*

Comment: You are right. But actually it does not fix the problem, see my edit.