# c++ async keyboard input(standard way)

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a c++ snake game in linux using ansi escape codes but i can't figure out a way to get async keyboard input. Im a beginner and i'm currently reading a c++ book, so i didn't cover multithreading yet.
Is there any chance to achieve this result in a "simple" way.(and standard if it's possible, i saw the kbhit solution)
[How to use kbhit and getch (C programming)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15603082/how-to-use-kbhit-and-getch-c-programming)
. Can i solve the problem reading from the */dev/input* event files?

Thank you guys.

Comment: There's no standard way. `/dev/input` is linux-specific, so it's not even remotely standard.

Comment: Are you asking about asynchronous keyboard input or per-key-stroke keyboard input? You can perform asynchronous keyboard input via `std::async` or `std::thread` but that doesn't look it's what you're actually asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ does not offer a standard way to asynchronously read the keyboard status.

boost asio, as in [read from keyboard using boost async_read and posix::stream_descriptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52308998/read-from-keyboard-using-boost-async-read-and-posixstream-descriptor) is one way. Some people consider boost like a "standard" or "normal" C++ extension.

Another way is to use a game library like SDL or SFML. You include their headers and you link with their libs.